# Polymer - Using Iron-icons for google-map-marker icon

Tags: google-maps, polymer

I'm looking for a way to set the icon for a google-map-marker, ideally I could use the iron-icons as they are already being used elsewhere in my project. I cannot find a way to set the icon marker properly.

Going off of the documentation for iron-icon element, I've tried:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<google-map-marker latitude="37.7749295" longitude="-122.41941550000001" icon="favorite">
</google-map-marker>
```

Custom icons work by setting: icon="someImg.png", but I'd really like to use the iron-icons for this. 
Other icons work on the page within iron-icon tags:

```
<iron-icon icon="favorite"></iron-icon>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Polymer developer:

> Right now, it's `icon` attribute is a simple URL to an image. The map
>   marker element would need to be taught how to use the svg images
>   within the iron icon set. The maps API takes a URL to an image as
>   well:
>   https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/master/google-map-marker.html#L236

Now a feature request:
https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/178